# How is the scroll top property used?

Tags: javascript

Hopefully a short question about scrollTop. Does it represent the distance of an element from the top of the page, but only if it has been scrolled?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: Thanks wil, but this source is why I ask, specifically the part about "gets or sets the number of pixels that an element's content is scrolled vertically." The scrolled vertically part is the one that gets me. If an element sits below the top of the page but the page isn't scrolled yet, is scrollTop equal to 0? Or is it really just the position measured from the top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any element, the scrollTop refers to the amount of scrolling is done by its contents.

Basically, think of every element of having a default scrollTop of 0. Then you add `overflow-y: scroll`. So now this element (I'll call it the container), now has a scrollbar. If the user scrolls inside the element, than the scrollTop **of the container** refers to the difference between the viewport of the contents of that element and the absolute position of the contents.

For a simple website with only overflow set on the body, then only the window.scrollTop will have something meaningful.

I hope this makes sense. There's a good image that I can't find at the moment. I'll try to find it if you need a visual